# Partial Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

This is the second time (and the first caused a whole lot of misery) that I have tried to upgrade Civi to the latest version and get an error message saying "Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded. You may want to reload the database with the backup and try the upgrade process again." The upgrade tasks screen reads 
/drupal
/civicrm.module:489
civicrm_invoke('upgrade', 'queue', 'ajax', 'runNext')   unknown:unknown
call_user_func_array('civicrm_invoke', Array)
/usr/home/recovery
/htdocs
/mtpleasantvillage.org
/drupal/includes
/menu.inc:517
menu_execute_active_handler()
/usr/home/recovery
/htdocs
/mtpleasantvillage.org
/drupal
/index.php:21
{main}

All of this is beyond me and challenges my understanding of Civi as a system that relatively naive users can use.
Maybe my internet connection hiccuped and the upload of the extracted file didn't go through, so I will try again. 
The last time this happened, I had to get my ISP to load the backup of the DB and then upload all the data (membership and contact info) that had changed since the last update. I will say that Civi seems to work just fine with what it thinks is a partial update. I did see a number of references to the 4.6 alpha DB when I was trying to upload 4.5. Could this be the problem?

Comment: What comes to mind immediately (though it doesn't answer your q) is the recommendation that you back up your database prior to any upgrade attempt. This would avoid your having to recover data that is lost.

Comment: You closing comment on 4.6 alpha DB makes me wonder if your original attempt was to 4.6?

Also, please provide more information as to what version of CiviCRM you are upgrading from, as well as what your CMS is (and it's version).

Comment: Have you tried to repeat the upgrade script? Something similar happened to me and the problem is that the upgrade stopped repeatedly. Running the upgrade process again to finish it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm now getting an error message that says the backup that was loaded is in MyISam format and Civi wants InnoDB and that this might result in data integrity issues. I'm following up with my ISP to see if this will solve it. I also see that I have lost my Civi Admin menu, so that may also be a data integrity issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up with an answer, it looks like your sql configuration is causing problems, based on your comment:

> I'm now getting an error message that says the backup that was loaded is in MyISam format and Civi wants InnoDB and that this might result in data integrity issues. I'm following up with my ISP to see if this will solve it. I also see that I have lost my Civi Admin menu, so that may also be a data integrity issue.